# setting 'path' in setmainfont causes compilation error

Tags: xetex, fontspec

This is a continuation from a problem I posted a long time ago, I keep coming back to it and still can't find a solution.

I have downloaded the minion pro font. If I have the files in the directory of the document I am compiling then there is no issue. If, however, I try I put the files somewhere else and specify a path then all sorts of problems crop up.

MWE of compiling fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[]{MinionPro-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}
I am writing words with my hands
\end{document}
```

MWE of a problem compile

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path=~/Documents/LaTeX-fonts/]{MinionPro-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}
I am writing words with my hands
\end{document}
```

This causes the errors `Missing \begin{document}` and font cannot be found, as do all my other efforts.

I have tried specifying with and without `Extension = .otf` added, also removing '.otf. from within font specification.

Running `ls ~/Documents/LaTeX-fonts/` in the terminal shows the files correctly.

If I have missed a link to a solution, or if anybody has any thoughts, it would be appreciated

Comment: Possibly `Path=\string~/Documents/LaTeX-fonts`

Comment: @egreg, you are outstanding. I hadn't seen or thought of that before. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that `~` is like a macro in LaTeX; in order to pass the “stringified” version to the OS, you need to prefix it by `\string`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path=\string~/Documents/LaTeX-fonts/]{MinionPro-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}
I am writing words with my hands
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same problem and solved, win10

**DO NOT** double click to `install`, it will install this font for the `current user`.

> (however, it shows the font in  `windows/fonts/` too)

`right-click` the font file, choose `install for all users`.

if you already installed the font:

1. go to `windows/fonts/`,
2. copy it to somewhere else,
3. `right-click` on it, and `install for all users`.

then enjoy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MinionPro-Medium}
\begin{document}
    ff g fhhhhh w \\

\end{document}
```

Ref: [Package fontspec Error: The font cannot be found on win10](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472262/package-fontspec-error-the-font-cannot-be-found-on-win10)