# Package fontspec Error: The font cannot be found on win10

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I have installed the Adobe Garamond Pro.otf fonts on my computer running win10, as shown in the following picture.
[image]

However, when I run xelatex, the otf fonts cannot be found.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[CJKchecksingle,CJKnumber]{xeCJK}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\begin{document}

test test test

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, the "fc-list" command cannot found the oft fonts.

Comment: First try running `fc-cache`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try running `fc-cache`.

If that doesn’t work, `\setmainfont{[Adobe Garamond Pro]}` or the family name reported by `otfinfo` might.

Loading a font by display name is no longer the preferred way, though, and you can instead try loading by filename.  That is, load the actual filenames you get when you `dir C:\Windows\Fonts\Adobe*.otf`, with options such as `UprightFont = *-Regular`, `ItalicFont = *-Italic` and so on.

Although that isn’t the problem in this case, that is the only way to load a font in XeTeX that is installed as part of the TeX distribution, rather than as a system font.

### Update

In TeX Live, LuaTeX (but not PDFTeX) now support setting the `OSFONTDIR` environment variable to

```
set OSFONTDIR="C:/Windows/fonts//;C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts//"
```

Unfortunately, the system `WINDIR` and `LOCALAPPDATA` environment variables use backslashes, and TeX Live expects forward slashes.

You would want to set this on your user account in your advanced system preferences.

Comment: Why do you say that ‘Loading a font by display name is now deprecated’? I don’t see anything about that in the documentation.

Comment: @Thérèse https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0MfY6EkiKc

Comment: Yikes! `texdoc youtube`? Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Thérèse I rephrased that sentence. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Thérèse The manual does say that loading by file name is the only way for XeTeX to see a font installed in a TeX, rather than a system, directory.

Comment: I have found the reason. Therer is an option "Installed for all users" from the Right Buttom when installing fonts. When chose it, the font would be installed in C:\Windows\Fonts\, or it would be installed somewhere else.

Comment: @On1gub Okay. The TeX engine is *supposed* to be able to load fonts installed for a single user, but what `luaotfload` (whose underlying library is used by LuaTeX) and `fc-match` (used by XeTeX) can actually do in the real world is different.

Comment: Note that square brackets in this context is not supported `fontspec` syntax — I may build in more explicit support in the future but the fact it works now is a bit of a coincidence.

Answer (score 30):

Same problem and solved, win10

**DONOT double click to install**, it will install this font for current user.

right click the font file, choose `install for all users`

[image]

There are two path,`C:\Windows\Fonts` and `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`,

`install for all users` will install the font file in first path, and **show** it in first path, `double click` will install the font file in second path, but **show** it in first path. This will mislead you.

Comment: This is indeed the solution! man I stuck on this for the whole day and you just saved me with this solution.

Comment: The right answer, Thanks !!

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me too

Answer (score 2):

When you install the collection of fonts for windows, select all of them, right click and  choose the “Install for all users” option, then build your document in latex . If the latex encountered  to errors again, delet the latex document and creat it again.

Comment: It really started to compile after deletion o_0 Thx!